# Recommended way to pass configuration to a Kafka client

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

A `KafkaProducer`, `KafkaConsumer` or an `AdminClient` requires some configuration to work. For example, if we don't set the `bootstrap.servers`, then it won't know where to connect.

At the beginning I used hardcoded string as keys, then I transitioned to constants defined in `ProducerConfig`, `ConsumerConfig` or `AdminClientConfig`, so that the:

```
config.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
```

Became:

```
config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092")
```

It seemed a good practice, because a wrong key will be found at compile time. But then, when I want to use a slightly less common settings, I need to switch between various classes:

```
config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092")
config.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, SecurityProtocol.SSL.name)
config.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_TYPE_CONFIG, "PKCS12")
```

`SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG` is not present in `ProducerConfig`, so I used `CommonClientConfigs` where it is defined, but the possible values are in `SecurityProtocol` enum. SSL related settings are in `SslConfigs` only.

It doesn't look very clean. Is there a better way of doing it, perhaps? Or should I stick to strings?

Comment: Looks good as is as far as keys are concerned. One improvement would be to externalise the values like `localhost:9092` so they are not hard coded in the source.

Comment: Personally, I move all these settings to a config file on the classpath, not put them in code at all

Answer (score 2):

To be honest this grouping makes kind of sense to me.
It tries to group configuration parameter for the producer, consumer and things which are common to both of them
Regarding `SslConfigs` it provides all SSL related configuration parameters.
The security protocol specification is a common parameter for producer and consumer and it's not just about SSL, it could be even PLAINTEXT so ... "no security".
Coming back to your specific question, I always prefer to use these declarations instead of hardcoded strings.
If one of them will change its value in the future you won't need to change your client code.